# Finding the json response of a page

Tags: php, json, web-scraping

I'm trying out using a json response for a webpage but I can't seem to get the json response from the webpage I'm trying to scrape.

This is the URL i'm testing: https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Convertible-Stainless-Steel-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-30-Inch-Actual-30-in/1000336623

Here's what I did to try and get the json responce (I'm on chrome)

```
Open Webpage -> inspect element -> network tab -> 'ip.json in filter -> refresh -> clicked 'all'
```

and here's what I get

[image]

Comment: Try typing 'json' into the filter and make sure 'all' is selected.  This resulted in a list of 8 files, all of which returned well formed JSON

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the settings of chrome, for example in FF this error warnings not happens. To fix it go to Developer Tools Settings of Chrome, and uncheck:

"Enable JavaScript source maps"
"Enable CSS source maps"
Then refresh Browser.

Comment: ok thank you! I'll try this out tomorrow and also try some python scripts to get this data